# Make PyLint and VSCode autocompletion understand relative import

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, pybind11, relative-import

In my Python project I want to import a self-compiled `.so`-file named `example.cpython-38-x86_64-linux.so` written with `pybind11` and stored in a subdirectory called `bin`.

To do so I use `import bin.example as example` which works just fine when executing the script.

However neither PyLint nor the autocompletion of VSCode seem to recognize this relative import. They just keep giving me squiggly lines under my import statement and no autocompletion whatsoever.

Is there a way to inform them about the present module or a completely different, more elegant way to include my library?

Comment: Could you describe for us where auto-completion cannot be provided? When I use it, although the wavy line appears here, the auto-completion can be used.

Comment: Sure. After importing `bin.example as example` I'd expect my classes and functions to show up when I type `example.` The same goes for tool-tips when trying to use the modules custom classes and functions.

Comment: When you import classes or methods from other python files, is auto-completion available? In VSCode, Python's automatic completion and code hints are provided by Python extensions and language services. You can try different Python language services. In addition, the [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) extension also provides outstanding language services and automatic completion functions.

Comment: Usually Pylint does the trick. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the fact, that I'm using a self-compiled library that has not been properly installed by any setup routine.

Comment: Currently in VSCode, Pylint is used as a python module to identify the content of python files (a Python code analysis tool), we can import other types of files into python files for use, but pylint cannot recognize the content of other types of files, so it cannot give automatic Finished options.

Comment: That does make sense. I am trying to make Pylint read a binary file after all. So I take, this is just an inconvenience I'll have to live with?

Comment: After all "Pylint" is a tool for "Python" code analysis.